# RRDTOOL and custom data

Tags: rrdtool

I'm trying to use rrdtool to make some graphs. But it's not working as i wanted...

Here is the situation:

I have a file with data that are collected every 30 seconds but i can access this file only the day after. For example if i want to graph Tuesday data, i have to wait Wednesday morning.
So what i have done is to create a new database with these information:

```
rrdtool create filename.rrd --step '30' 'DS:t634:GAUGE:60:U:U' 'RRA:AVERAGE:0.5:1:1000'
```

collected data:

```
rrdtool update filename.rrd 1390231080:1
rrdtool update filename.rrd 1390231110:2
rrdtool update filename.rrd 1390231140:3
rrdtool update filename.rrd 1390231170:4
....
```

generated a graph:

```
rrdtool graph 'graph.png' --width '400' --height '100' 'DEF:T634=filename.rrd:t634:AVERAGE' 'LINE1:T634#0000FF:T634'
```

I have a graph with no line on it...

Is my rrd file creation false?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your 'rrdtool graph' call does not specify a start and end time for the graph.  The default is a 1day graph from the current time. If the data are historical, the most recent data point may be outside the default graph time window.  Specify a start and end time point in your graph request.

You can verify that the data are in the RRD by using an 'rrdtool fetch' request.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem... There was too few data in the file and the graph offset time was too high...

Thanks a lot for your help!